# Identity Server 4 Getting 401 with valid access token .net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, identityserver4, identity, asp.net-core-3.1

I am using Identity server 4 in my .NET Core 3.1 API Application. I am getting successful token on local server https://localhost:[port]/connect/token and when i use the bearer token to access authorize method , i am always getting 401 error.

I have only 1 controller with [Authorize] added.

Here's my startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddCookiePolicy();
    
            services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>(identityOptions =>
            {
                identityOptions.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                identityOptions.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 6;
                identityOptions.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
            })
            .AddUserManager<CustomUserManager>()
            .AddUserStore<CustomUserStorage>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppIdentityDbContext>()
            .AddSignInManager<CustomSignInManager>()
            .AddErrorDescriber<CustomIdentityErrorDescriber>();

            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
                options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };
            });

            var sqlConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlServer");

            var migrationsAssembly = typeof(AppUser).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;
            services.AddIdentityServer()
                    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
                    .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApis())
                    .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
                    .AddOperationalStore(options =>
                    {
                        options.ConfigureDbContext = builder => builder.UseSqlServer(sqlConnectionString, db => MigrationAndRetryBuilder(db, migrationsAssembly));
                        options.DefaultSchema = AppIdentityDbContext.Schema;
                    })
                    .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
                    {
                        options.ConfigureDbContext = builder => builder.UseSqlServer(sqlConnectionString, db => MigrationAndRetryBuilder(db, migrationsAssembly));
                        options.DefaultSchema = AppIdentityDbContext.Schema;
                    });

            services.AddControllers();


            services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
            .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
            {
                options.Authority = Configuration["Authentication:Authorization"];
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.Audience = "ap1";
            });
        }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IdentityServerDatabaseInitialization databaseInitialization)
            {   
    
                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                    // app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
                }
                else
                {
                    app.UseHsts();
    
                }

                if (Configuration.GetValue<bool>("UseSecureHeaders", false))
                {
                    ConfigureAppSecureHeaders(app);
                }
    
                var pathBase = Configuration["PATH_BASE"];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pathBase))
                {
                    loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Startup>().LogDebug("Using PATH BASE '{pathBase}'", pathBase);
                    app.UsePathBase(pathBase);
                }
                app.UseStaticFiles();

                app.UseHttpsRedirection();
                app.UseRouting();
                app.UseCors("AllowAll");
                app.UseIdentityServer();
                app.UseAuthorization();
    
                app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                {
                    endpoints.MapControllers();
                });
    
            }
```

Here's my config.cs:

```
public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
        {
            return new IdentityResource[]
            {
                new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
                new IdentityResources.Profile(),
                new IdentityResources.Email(),
                new IdentityResources.Address(),
                new IdentityResources.Phone()
            };
        }

        public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApis()
        {
            return new List<ApiResource>
            {
                new ApiResource("ap1","My Api")
                {
                    Description="Api with Bearer Token",
                    Scopes= new []{ new Scope("ap1"), new Scope("offline_access"),new Scope(IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.ScopeName) },
                    ApiSecrets= new []{ new Secret("secret".Sha256()) }
                }
            };
        }

        public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
        {
            return new List<Client>
            {
                new Client
                {
                    RequireConsent=false,
                    ClientId = "ap1",
                    ClientName="My Api",
                    AllowOfflineAccess=true,

                    // no interactive user, use the clientid/secret for authentication
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
                    // scopes that client has access to
                    AllowedScopes = { "ap1", "offline_access", IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.ScopeName },

                    // secret for authentication
                    ClientSecrets =
                    {
                        new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                    },
                }
            };
        }
```

**Solution**

In the end i decide to separate IdentityServer in its own service and now everything is working with a simple configure

Comment: try to enable debug logging and see what's going on in the logs at that moment, there should be some hints

Comment: for the moment, as far as i know, the problem is with the ConfigureApplicationCookie and the method OrRedirectToLogin. In there i force the result to be 401 everytime, instead of redirect to the endpoint i want to use

Comment: I would put IdentityServer in its own service and not mix it with your client or API, as it makes everything so much harder to reason about and debug.

Comment: I want to do this beacause i dont want to have 2 differents apis, but i think it would be better one for the identity and the other one to get the info i need. If i have no other options i would do that, for the moment i'll keep trying to have it all in the same service

Comment: Well, in the end i decide to separate IdentityServer in its own service and now everything is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i decide to separate IdentityServer in its own service and now everything is working with a simple configure